# How to add users to Jasig CAS ?

Tags: logging, cas, jasig

Now I have only test user account, how can I add the others ?

And one more point, how to connect each user to certain page ?

Answer (score 0):

> Now I have only test user account, how can I add the others ?

Well, you could add users in deployerConfigContext.xml in the primaryAuthenticationHandler bean. 
https://github.com/Jasig/cas/blob/6c3df3a5f42d2d8b771ba773aeda3ba5a4c525e3/cas-server-webapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/deployerConfigContext.xml

But you should probably write your own AuthenticationHandler or reuse an existing one with a database connector.

> And one more point, how to connect each user to certain page ?

That is not was jasig is for. Jasig is a Single-Sign-On Server which redirects the user to the application where he came from. The application itself should check if the resolved principal has the privileges to access the site.